# Leer un fichero que esta siendo escrito por otro programa

Tags: c#

Tengo una serie de ficheros que son generados por otro software, se crean aproximadamente cada hora y durante esa hora se le insertan registros muy rapidamente,estoy intentando desarrollar una herramienta que me permita ir leyendo ese fichero o los que se hayan creado en el espacio de tiempo desde la ultima vez que di la orden de lectura, pero cuando intento leer el fichero (desde un programa que estoy haciendo en C#) que esta siendo escrito en la hora puntual donde seleccione obtengo el error:

```
El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo C:/Documents/MyArchivo.txt
```

Hay forma de leer este fichero mientras se va llenando de registros en "Tiempo real"?

La forma actual en que intento leer es asi:

```
StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(fi.FullName);
string sLine = "";
ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
while (sLine != null)
{
sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
if (sLine != null)
arrText.Add(sLine);
}
objReader.Close();
```

Alguna idea de como leer mientras el otro proceso tiene ocupado el fichero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que abrir el archivo en modo lectura:

```cs
var filePath = fi.FullName;
ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();

using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (var objReader = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.Default)) {
    string sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
    while (sLine != null)
    {
        arrText.Add(sLine);
        sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esa forma ha funcionado.